# Create a modal popUp for each object using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-modal

I have a list of cards in react and, in each card i have a button.

That button, when clicked, should display a modal popUp with some information but i cant create a modal for each entry because de data target is always the same.

I tried to change the data-target on my modal by concateneting the "#" with the name of the object but it doesn´t work.

Here is the code:

```
 {this.state.groups.map((groups) => {
 return ( 
    <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#' + groups.name + '" >
      {groups.name}
    </button>

    <div className="modal fade" id={groups.name} tabIndex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" />

 )})}
```

Comment: Not really sure why its not working.
But I am suggesting using `React.createPortal` for popups.
https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html

Its better to have one single modal, instead of rendering a modal for every single button.

Comment: Thanks but it has to be with normal boostrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of this `data-target="#' + groups.name + '"` maybe you can try this

```
data-target={`#${groups.name}`}
```

Comment: what is not working? when you inspect your DOM, what do you see as data-target?

Comment: The react developer tools says that the datatarget is data-target:"#${groups.name}"

Comment: try this

data-target={\`#${groups.name}\`}

Comment: data-target={\`#${groups.name}\`}